# Change the user's password through API in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I'm wondering if there is a way to change a user's password through API?

Apparently, this was possible by using SetUserPreferences (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Edit_-_Set_user_preferences), but this is no longer supported. And the API Options feature (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Options) doesn't seem to have the option to change passwords.

Is there a way that allows me to do such a thing?

Comment: There never was a setuserpreferences API (as the text on the top of that page explains: "This is an old proposal. There is no action=setuserpreferences implemented.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via the (not very well documented) [changeauthenticationdata](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=changeauthenticationdata) API. The API is fairly generic as the authentication system might change from wiki to wiki and does not necessarily involve passwords.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but how can I specify what user I'm trying to change the password for? There is only a parameter for the new password but no parameter for the user.

Comment: You can't, it is for changing credentials of the current user (ie. for building alternative UIs by which the user can change their password). There's a [`resetpassword` API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Resetpassword) and a [changePassword.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ChangePassword.php) maintenance script.